# What is the difference between int parseInt(String s) and Integer.valueOf(String s)? Also What is radix with a numerical parameter {10 or etc}

Tags: java

I have used these two in Java and BlueJ but I am not sure where the difference between these two lies. Also in my book in the description given for parseInt there is a mention of radix 10. What exactly is radix 10?

Comment: radix = base, base 10 is our normal notation: 234 = 2*10² + 3*10 * 4.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The two methods are almost the same in terms of logic.

The difference is that `valueOf` returns an `Integer` and `parseInt` returns an `int`.

You can see that both call `parseInt(s, 10)`, which means they treat the input `String` as a number of radix (base) 10 (i.e. a decimal number).

```
public static Integer valueOf(String s) throws NumberFormatException {
    return Integer.valueOf(parseInt(s, 10));
}

public static int parseInt(String s) throws NumberFormatException {
    return parseInt(s,10);
}
```